# gmail inline font size not stripped but not obeyed anyway

Tags: html, styles, webmail

I use very simple inline styling like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">some text<br>
<span style="font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color:#333333;">
some other text
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the Text "some other text" doesn't display any different from the text "some text" in gmail (and in Outlook.com)-- although the inline styles ARE still there in the gmail page source code. It doesn't matter if I use px or pt or no unit at all.

So what is wrong here, and how can I get other text size and color in gmail?

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/SC975/1/

Comment: Huh? It works now, so WTH happened in the last half hour?

Comment: No, doesn't work anymore again. What the...?

Comment: OK somehow I got it to work now :) However, the line spacing is the same (i.e. too large) no matter how small the text is! What can I do to get plain, normal line spacing also for small text?